# How to match values of several variables to a variable in a look up table?

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lookup

I have two datasets:

```
loc <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
id1 <- c(NA,9,3,4,5)
id2 <- c(2,3,7,5,6)
id3 <- c(2,NA,5,NA,7)
cost1 <- c(10,20,30,40,50)
cost2 <- c(50,20,30,30,50)
cost3 <- c(40,20,30,10,20)
dt <- data.frame(loc,id1,id2,id3,cost1,cost2,cost3)


id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
rate <- c(0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3)
lookupd_tb <- data.frame(id,rate)
```

what I want to do, is to match the values in dt with lookup_tb for id1,id2 and id3 and if there is a match, multiply rate for that id to its related cost.

This is my approach:

```
dt <- dt %>% 
left_join(lookupd_tb , by=c("id1"="id")) %>%
dplyr :: mutate(cost1 = ifelse(!is.na(rate), cost1*rate, cost1)) %>% 
dplyr :: select (-rate)
```

what I am doing now, works fine but I have to repeat it 3 times for each variable and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this(probably using apply family?)

I tried to join all three variables with id in my look up table but when rate is joined with my dt, all the costs (cost1, cost2 and cost3) will be multiply by the same rate which I don't want.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7):

A `base R` approach would be to loop through the columns of 'id' using `sapply/lapply`, get the `match`ing index from the 'id' column of 'lookupd_tb', based on the index, get the corresponding 'rate', `replace` the `NA` elements with 1, multiply with 'cost' columns and update the 'cost' columns

```
nmid <- grep("id", names(dt))
nmcost <- grep("cost", names(dt))

dt[nmcost] <- dt[nmcost]*sapply(dt[nmid], function(x) {
         x1 <- lookupd_tb$rate[match(x, lookupd_tb$id)]
          replace(x1, is.na(x1), 1) })
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, we can loop through the sets of columns i.e. 'id' and 'cost' with `purrr::map2`, then do the same approach as above.  The only diference is that here we created new columns instead of updating the 'cost' columns

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>% 
   select(nmid) %>% 
   map2_df(., dt %>% 
               select(nmcost), ~  
                 .x %>% 
                     match(., lookupd_tb$id) %>%
                     lookupd_tb$rate[.] %>% 
                     replace(., is.na(.),1) * .y ) %>%
    rename_all(~ paste0("costnew", seq_along(.))) %>%
    bind_cols(dt, .)
```

Comment: @EmmaNej  That is according to your o`ifelse` statement

Comment: I wanted the original value and your approach works fine! Thanks!

Comment: can you please explain the place holder (.) and ~ and .x .y in the code? I have a hard time understanding these!

Comment: @EmmaNej  `map2` takes two arguments and the way we extract the values in those arguments when we use with `~` is `.x` and `.y` in the same order. i.e. `.x` would be `dt %>% select(nmid)` and `.y` would be `dt %>% select(nmcost)` in other and these are looped through columns, so each corresponding column of 'dt[nmid]`  have a corresponding column in `dt[nmcost]`

Comment: @EmmaNej I think it is because of the way we make it too much piping.  To understand better try `map2(dt[nmid], dt[nmcost], ~ .x)` and `map2(dt[nmid], dt[nmcost], ~ .y)` it will be more clear

Answer (score 3):

In `tidyverse` you can also try an alternative approach by transforming the data from wide to long

```
  library(tidyverse)
  dt %>% 
  # data transformation to long
  gather(k, v, -loc) %>% 
  mutate(ID=paste0("costnew", str_extract(k, "[:digit:]")),
         k=str_remove(k, "[:digit:]")) %>% 
  spread(k, v) %>% 
  # left_join and calculations of new costs
  left_join(lookupd_tb , by="id") %>% 
  mutate(cost_new=ifelse(is.na(rate), cost,rate*cost)) %>% 
  #  clean up and expected output
  select(loc, ID, cost_new) %>% 
  spread(ID, cost_new) %>% 
  left_join(dt,., by="loc")  # or %>% bind_cols(dt, .)
  loc id1 id2 id3 cost1 cost2 cost3 costnew1 costnew2 costnew3
1   a  NA   2   2    10    50    40       10       40       32
2   b   9   3  NA    20    20    20       20       14       20
3   c   3   7   5    30    30    30       21        9       15
4   d   4   5  NA    40    30    10       24       15       10
5   e   5   6   7    50    50    20       25       20        6
```

The idea ist to bring the data in suitable long format for the `lef_joining` using a `gather` & `spread` combination with new index columns `k` and `ID`. After the calculation we will transform to the expected output using a second `spread` and binding to `dt`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the result is not correct. I want to change cost2 and cost3 based on the new rates and appending rate like that would lead to the wrong results.

Comment: Yup, that does the job! Thanks!